# Property wrappers and SwiftUI environment: how can a property wrapper access the environment of its enclosing object?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The [@FetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest) property wrapper that ships with SwiftUI helps declaring properties that are auto-updated whenever a Core Data storage changes. You only have to provide a fetch request:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: /* some fetch request */)
    var myValues: FetchedResults<MyValue>
}
```

The fetch request can't access the storage without a managed object context. This  context has to be passed in the view's environment.

And now I'm quite puzzled.

**Is there any public API that allows a property wrapper to access the environment of its enclosing object, or to have SwiftUI give this environment to the property wrapper?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Xcode 13 (haven't tested on earlier versions) as long as your property wrapper implements `DynamicProperty` you can use the `@Environment` property wrapper.

The following example create a property wrapper that's read the `lineSpacing` from the current environment.

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct LineSpacing: DynamicProperty {
    @Environment(\.lineSpacing) var lineSpacing: CGFloat
    
    var wrappedValue: CGFloat {
        lineSpacing
    }
}
```

Then you can use it just like any other property wrapper:

```swift
struct LineSpacingDisplayView: View {
    @LineSpacing private var lineSpacing: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Line spacing: \(lineSpacing)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LineSpacingDisplayView()
            LineSpacingDisplayView()
                .environment(\.lineSpacing, 99)
        }
    }
}
```

This displays:

> Line spacing: 0.000000
>
> Line spacing: 99.000000

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, @rraphael :-) `DynamicProperty` is indeed how the `@Query` property wrapper (similar to `@FetchRequest` for GRDB) is implemented: https://github.com/groue/GRDBQuery

Answer (score 5):

We don't know the exact internals of how SwiftUI is implemented, but we can make some educated guesses based on the information we have available.

First, `@propertyWrapper`s *do not* get automatic access to any kind of context from their containing struct/class.  You can check out [the spec](https://github.com/DougGregor/swift-evolution/blob/property-wrappers/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md) for evidence of that.  This was discussed a few times during the evolution process, but not accepted.

Therefore, we know that something has to happen at runtime for the framework to inject the `@EnvironmentObject`(here the `NSManagedObjectContext`) into the `@FetchRequest`.  For an example of how to do something like that via the `Mirror` API, you can see [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747738/467209). (By the way, that was written before `@Property` was available, so the specific example is no longer useful).

However, [this article](https://kateinoigakukun.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/06/09/081831) suggests a sample implementation of `@State` and speculates (based on
an assembly dump) that rather than using the Mirror API, SwiftUI is using [TypeMetadata](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeMetadata.rst) for speed:

> #### Reflection without Mirror
>
> There is still a way to get fields without using Mirror. It's using metadata.
>
> Metadata has Field Descriptor which contains accessors for fields of the type. It's possible to get fields by using it.
>
> My various experiments result AttributeGraph.framework uses metadata internally. AttributeGraph.framework is a private framework that SwiftUI use internally for constructing ViewGraph.
>
> You can see it by the symbols of the framework.
>
> $ nm /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AttributeGraph.framework/AttributeGraph
> There is AG::swift::metadata_visitor::visit_field in the list of symbols. i didn't analysis the whole of assembly code but the name implies that AttributeGraph use visitor pattern to parse metadata.

Comment: Excellent write-up, very well put, and full of actually useful information!

Comment: Another interesting link: https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/419

Answer (score 1):

A `DynamicProperty` struct can simply declare `@Environment` and it will be set before `update` is called e.g.

```
struct FetchRequest2: DynamicProperty {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context
    @StateObject private var controller = FetchController()

    func update(){
        // context will now be valid
        // set the context on the controller and do some fetching.
    }
```