# How to build a Swift object that can control the mutability of its stored properties

Tags: ios, swift, immutability, property-wrapper

I would like to create a set of objects that exhibit the following behavior:

1. Each has a BOOL property -- call it `dataLocked` -- that is initially false.
2. Each has a set of stored properties whose values may be set, but not read, whenever `dataLocked == false`.
3. Those same stored properties may be read, but not set, whenever `dataLocked == true`
4. `dataLocked` can be set only once.

Below is a sample implementation.  Is there any Swifty way to achieve this without having to reproduce all those get and set conditions for every property of every object?

The neatest solution I believe would be to create a Property Wrapper, but I haven't found any way to make the wrapper change its behaviors based on the value of the `locked` property in the enclosing object.

```
class ImmutableObjectBase {
    var dataLocked: Bool = false {
        didSet { dataLocked = true }
    }
    private var _someIntValue: Int = 42
    var someIntValue: Int {
        get {
            precondition(dataLocked, "Cannot access object properties until object is locked")
            return _someIntValue
        }
        set {
            precondition(!dataLocked, "Cannot modify object properties after object is locked")
            _someIntValue = newValue
        }
    }
}

let i = ImmutableObjectBase()
i.someIntValue = 100
i.dataLocked = true     // or false, it doesn't matter!
print (i.someIntValue)  // 100
print (i.dataLocked)    // true
i.someIntValue = 200    // aborts
```

Comment: To be honest, mutability implemented at runtime is almost useless. If you give us the exact use case, we might propose a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

protocol PropertyWrapperWithLockableObject {
    var enclosingObject: LockableObjectBase! {get set}
}

@propertyWrapper
class Lockable<Value>: PropertyWrapperWithLockableObject {
    private var _wrappedValue: Value
    var enclosingObject: LockableObjectBase!
    
    init (wrappedValue: Value) { self._wrappedValue = wrappedValue }
    
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            precondition(enclosingObject.isLocked, "Cannot access object properties until object is locked")
            return _wrappedValue
        }
        set {
            precondition(!enclosingObject.isLocked, "Cannot modify object properties after object is locked")
            _wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}

class LockableObjectBase {
    internal var isLocked: Bool = false {
        didSet { isLocked = true }
    }
    
    init () {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in mirror.children {
            if var child = child.value as? PropertyWrapperWithLockableObject {
                child.enclosingObject = self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class DataObject: LockableObjectBase {
    @Lockable var someString: String = "Zork"
    @Lockable var someInt: Int
    
    override init() {
        someInt = 42
        // super.init() // Not needed in this particular example.
    }
}

var testObject = DataObject()
testObject.isLocked = true
print(testObject.someInt, testObject.someString) // 42, Zork
testObject.isLocked = false             // Has no effect: Object remained locked
print (testObject.isLocked)             // true
testObject.someInt = 2                  // Aborts the program
```

arsenius's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686026/can-a-swift-property-wrapper-reference-the-owner-of-the-property-its-wrapping) provided the vital reflection clue!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for your problem, but it is probably not the cleanest way.
You might find a better way if you check [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/property-wrapper-accessing-enclosing-class/38359)
or [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-an-associatedobject-property-wrapper-impossible/32172/5).

I managed to lock and unlock the properties by using this [tutorial](https://davedelong.com/blog/2021/04/02/custom-property-wrappers-for-swiftui/):

```
import Foundation
import Combine

public class Locker: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var isLocked = false
    public static let shared = Locker()
    private init() {}
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Lockable<Value> {
    private var _wrappedValue: Value
    
    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self._wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            precondition(Locker.shared.isLocked, "Cannot access object properties until object is locked")
            return _wrappedValue
        }
        set {
            precondition(!Locker.shared.isLocked, "Cannot modify object properties after object is locked")
            _wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}

class ImmutableObjectBase {
    var isLocked: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            Locker.shared.isLocked = self.isLocked
        }
    }
    @Lockable var someString: String = "initial"
    @Lockable var someInt: Int = 1
}


var i = ImmutableObjectBase()
i.isLocked = true
print(i.someInt, i.someString) // 1, initial
i.isLocked = false
i.someInt = 2
i.someString = "new value"
i.isLocked = true
print(i.someInt, i.someString) // 2, new value
```

EDIT:

I just found a similar question with an accepted answer.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686026/can-a-swift-property-wrapper-reference-the-owner-of-the-property-its-wrapping)

Comment: Lovo, thank you so much!  You gave me all the clues I needed to crack it.  I like your solution, but for two things.  It doesn't satisfy my 4th criterion above, though that is a trivial change.  More importantly, while I can see why you resorted to using a global singleton, that would not work for me, as I plan to create lots of "lockable" objects within on app.  But your code and the other examples you point to gave me a solution, which I shall post below.